# Where does clientAction field in POST come from?

Tags: php, forms, post

I have an HTML form with several fields. The form is submitted to a server-side PHP script. For **some** users (very few), there is an additional field clientAction among submitted POST fields.

The field has one of such values 552.click, 553.click, 550.click, etc

User-agent of all these users is different, although, it seems, that all or most of them come from mobile devices.

So the questions are: what is this field, where does it come from and why is it needed? Is this a documented behavior?

P.S. May be an unrelated issue, but hidden fields are missing from POST when the clientAction field is present.

Comment: Are you using any framework?

Comment: @Leonardo no framework

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing similar entries *(containing `123.click`, `456.click`, etc)* in various traffic logs, the associated User-Agent appears to reveal a pattern identifying traffic using "[UC Browser](http://www.ucweb.com/ucbrowser/)" from UCWeb Inc.

Some example UA strings also containing matching `clientAction` POST field in the request:

- **UCWEB/2.0** (MIDP-2.0; U; Adr 4.4.2; en-US; irisX8) U2/1.0.0 **UCBrowser/10.0.0.556** U2/1.0.0 Mobile
- **UCWEB/2.0** (MIDP-2.0; U; Adr 4.1.1; en-US; AURUS_III) U2/1.0.0 **UCBrowser/9.8.0.534** U2/1.0.0 Mobile
- NokiaX2-02/2.0 (12.04) Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 **UCWEB/2.0** (Java; U; MIDP-2.0; en-US; NokiaX2-02) U2/1.0.0 **UCBrowser/9.5.0.449** U2/1.0.0 Mobile
- **UCWEB/2.0**(BlackBerry; U; 9.16.0.209; en-us; 9790/9.16.0.209) U2/1.0.0 **UCBrowser/8.1.0.216** U2/1.0.0 Mobile

Comment: In my case, the occurrences were not limited to one browser only. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to those logs, so can't give any examples.